# Access: Move to previous record until BOF

Tags: ms-access, vba

I found information on how to keep moving through the records until EOF.  The solution(s) were simple and worked perfectly (Thanks!).

The one I used was:

```
If Me.CurrentRecord < Me.Recordset.RecordCount Then
    ' ...
End If
```

### What I'd like to do is reverse this process.  Is there a simple way to detect when I'm on the first record and if I click a "Previous Record" button it will detect that there is no previous record and will not generate a "can't go to specified record" error?  In other words, how do I detect BOF?

Okay, I'm back.  I thought it worked, but it doesn't.  I'm still getting the "Can't go to specified Record."  Here is the code I'm using.

```
If Recordset.BOF Then
Beep
MsgBox "You are at the beginning."
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst
Else
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acPrevious
End If
```

Comment: `If Recordset.BOF Then`

Comment: Please add your code to your original post !

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is BOF means BEFORE first record.

And ONLY WHEN you move OFF the first record, or the last record, then BOF/EOF becomes true.

The next problem is when the form is on the first record, then BOF is STILL = FALSE.

You cannot MOVE a form off the record by using docmd.goto Record (this is a UI command and as such BOF/EOF will never occur without first seeing a UI error message.

The simple solution is to thus move the record using the recordset and NOT the form command.

By the time the form moves to BOF/EOF, then you already have a error message.

So use the forms recordset to move the pointer.

This code should work:

```
Me.Recordset.MovePrevious
If Recordset.BOF Then
   MsgBox "at beginning"
   Recordset.MoveFirst
End If
```